# The withRouter wrapper for React Router v6 correctly typed without any

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

In order to not rebuild everything from class components to functional components I need to use the wrapper from the React Router [Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/faq):

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

However I need to correct types for `Component` and `props` in Typescript. (A quick test with any shows it works). But what are the correct types that I need to use?

This is what I tried, give `Component` the `Function` type but still not sure with props as I want to avoid to use any..

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

type IComponentWithRouterProp = {
  [x: string]: any;
};

function withRouter(Component: Function) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: IComponentWithRouterProp) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

**EDIT:**

So I found out that what I am looking for is [React.ComponentType](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9206), which is a union of ComponentClass and ComponentFunction.

But when I use `Component: React.ComponentType` then TS throws an error at my router in the return - `router={{ location, navigate, params }}`

```
Type '{ router: { location: Location; navigate: NavigateFunction; params: Readonly<Params<string>>; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'router' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

So this throws a new error, how can I solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are indeed some blogs about typing the FAQ proposed `withRouter` implementation, e.g. https://whereisthemouse.com/how-to-use-withrouter-hoc-in-react-router-v6-with-typescript

But it looks like it was using a previous version of the FAQ, where `location`, `params` and `navigate` props were directly inlined as props keys, whereas the new FAQ gathers them in a single `router` dictionary. It all depends on how your class components expect to receive these props.

Since you say that ignoring type issues (typically with `any`) works in your project, then it complies with this form. So let's adapt the typings:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export interface WithRouterProps {
    location: ReturnType<typeof useLocation>;
    params: Record<string, string>;
    navigate: ReturnType<typeof useNavigate>;
}

function withRouter<CProps extends { router: WithRouterProps }>(Component: React.ComponentType<CProps>) {
    function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: Omit<CProps, "router">) {
        let location = useLocation();
        let navigate = useNavigate();
        let params = useParams();
        return <Component {...(props as CProps)} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
    }

    return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

Let's try it:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component<{ name: string; router: WithRouterProps }> {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }
}

// Bare component expects name and router props
<>
    <Welcome name="Foo" /> {/* Error: Property 'router' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'Readonly<{ name: string; router: WithRouterProps; }>'.(2769)*/}
    <Welcome name="Foo" router={({} as WithRouterProps)} />
</>

const WelcomeWithRouter = withRouter(Welcome);

// withRouter'ed component expects only name, router will be automatically provided
<>
    <WelcomeWithRouter name="Foo" />
    <WelcomeWithRouter name="Foo" router={({} as WithRouterProps)} /> {/* Error: Property 'router' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<{ name: string; router: WithRouterProps; }, "router">'.(2322) */}
</>
```

Looks good!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=4&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzgFcBnJAGQjRRmAgDsAaRiwByKAG7AA5lySDmSAAoooKEEzgBfONlwEi6GAFocDGEiiGAJrjLlySAB7V4wXmaiZ0SOAHVgMAAsECFNzBRwwdVpyOFi4ABsOLh5eAC5EJBgGKF4AFQBPMCQAHhhCpAhMITYk7j4APgo4uDBlVSZ05DRoS2KmGChXSUF+wd5JRpi43nEpGU7M7Lzy0vLK6tEJaTNJjTtMBl4MFLgAd38gkPdigGFwiEi4RzNeSyi4E3d0v0Dg0Kh7o8NPUABQ3XCQXhINwLAwAOnB4D40JgBSKt0BTHqAEo6FNYgcjnVeHBEZCUT9Lv9ASCwBEOnAAPIgfwY+mCQhXcz4HF45rNeKZBK1E4AXmq7E4xJB2Ka-NigvgMy2Mjg4vkmzmZhlcvlipabTUauqShUah1+P5RCyOTgtwhyLcdDhLtp9LgKHUd3p2K0n3Moto9ESUpSgmVWtkBrN6g0WgA9JNmntLdalqSHVC3JS-u5ARQU45nHBLEhPAx4vBzr8uVAKOQ0PFPeofEh4t0QN5ntC3hl4WTHTBivQZp30qMhqQPrXvhdc2F3cC+XEiK9zDLl-K07bigEAIz1AASbcSglogWATDhdIeV9HSA0xXj+6TcT2Kfj8bgACFlN4O+STpFkgGDqPeHqvNO-wtPS5DFPUlrFK27a4N496ivgABiEAQPgcCJnQ8YAFRwAAolAOBQOkgLmGUcAAOT+lA9FwJecAskwTBDKxJJlEUDEjqoSDjgMk6aCxABGpgfEgACODDAEQlg8XAfHePRyAoNYvDxPkw5wPeIljJIU5MbONbUvSU7AvRcIggATAA7AAbAAnNiRHxnszRIW2HZoUJGHYbhUHuIGIK0Fonq+HOtaYr6+EIU+CENnw-S+H5qE5rWxrVlS7ggsh-mynYn5nLF-z0UgykAYOTxOCBMDqHwukGUJghMeV8TxHAEneCgpi4MknDdfkMEQBIpaWHBCE+UVWUVe4bWdkFOF4YmiHzZ22XQehWFraFAa0BFUUtotC63glBG0MRZEUdA1ERLRY2MbWLHWEgYEQPAjiXvAfCqeUDEAJJuGMXFoAAgjAolSWY6gAGRMiyQ6CWOcATuMpkzjFFl5lZmgckxPK2Q5ADM9n2binl7Ml5BAA)

Answer (score 4):

I think this solves your problem:

```
import React from "react"
import {
    NavigateFunction,
    Params,
    useLocation,
    useNavigate,
    useParams,
} from "react-router-dom"

interface Router {
    location: Location
    navigate: NavigateFunction
    params: Readonly<Params<string>>
}

export interface PropsWithRouter {
    router: Router
}

export function withRouter<T extends PropsWithRouter>(
    Component: React.FC<T>
): React.FC<Omit<T, "router">> {
    function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: T) {
        let location = useLocation()
        let navigate = useNavigate()
        let params = useParams()
        return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />
    }

    return ComponentWithRouterProp as React.FC<Omit<T, "router">>
}
```

And then when you are creating components do something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { PropsWithRouter, withRouter } from "./withRouter"

interface TestProps extends PropsWithRouter {
    test: number
}

const Test: React.FC<TestProps> = ({ router, test }) => {
    return <div>Hello World!</div>
}

export default withRouter(Test)
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand the interface for the Router and then PropsWithRouter. But why do I need the ..): React.FC<Omit<T, "router">>and for what does the Omit stand for?

Comment: Omit is to remove properties from object type. Learn more here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys

Comment: We need to do this, because when we would use component: `<Test />` we would need to pass router props `<Test router={...} />`; And when we add `React.FC<Omit<T, "router">>` we do not need to pass it. I don't know if I said it clear but we just need to do this so we don't get typescript errors